# XML - Alternative to starting a element with a number

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, dictionary

I am currently programming a project in vb.net which displays data on data grids.

I am currently getting my data from excel files which I convert into a XML file using a map. The problem is that my program uses numbers as elements and there isn't any other way I can think of., not using numbers at the start.

Is there any alternative I can use?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<record>
<F>30</F>
<0></0>
<1></1>
<2>0</2>
<3>0</3>
<4>0</4>
<5>0</5>
<6>-0.001</6>
<7>-0.001</7>
<8>-0.001</8>
<9>-0.001</9>
<10>-0.001</10>

</record>
<record>
<C>40</C>
<0>-0.001</0>
<1>-0.001</1>
<2>-0.001</2>
<3>-0.001</3>
<4>-0.001</4>
<5>-0.001</5>
<6>-0.002</6>
<7>-0.002</7>
<8>-0.002</8>
<9>-0.002</9>
<10>-0.002</10>
</record>

</data-set>
```

Cheers, Steve

Comment: "Alternavice", is that a sci-fi police thriller I should know about? Oops, damn, someone edited the title while I was writing this joke. Never mind, nothing to see here.

Comment: Why use XML here can't you keep in CSV? If the data are data tables etc